# How Can I Manually Revalidate a Dynamic Next.js Route, From an API Route?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I have a Next.js application with a dynamic page for displaying resources: `/resource/[id]`.  Whenever a user edits (say) resource #5, I want to regenerate the page `/resource/5` in Next's cache.

I have an API route (in my `/pages` directory) that handles the resource editing. From what I've read, I should be able to make it refresh the display route by doing:

```
response.revalidate(`/resource/${id}/`);
```

However, that doesn't work; I get the error:

```
Error: Failed to revalidate /resource/2153/: Invalid response 200
    at revalidate (/home/jeremy/GoblinCrafted/next/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:388:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
- error unhandledRejection: Error: Failed to revalidate /resource/2153/: Invalid response 200
    at revalidate (/home/jeremy/GoblinCrafted/next/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:388:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  digest: undefined
```

I guess Next is trying to revalidate through an HTTP request, but the revalidation endpoint moved?  I'm not exactly sure why this fails.

**EDIT:** I dug into the Next source code, and it seems like `revalidate` is just making a mock request to the route that is being revalidated.  If you look at `node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js` you'll see:

```
async revalidate({ urlPath , revalidateHeaders , opts  }) {
        const mocked = (0, _mockrequest.createRequestResponseMocks)({
            url: urlPath,
            headers: revalidateHeaders
        });
        const handler = this.getRequestHandler();
        await handler(new _node.NodeNextRequest(mocked.req), new _node.NodeNextResponse(mocked.res));
        await mocked.res.hasStreamed;
        if (mocked.res.getHeader("x-nextjs-cache") !== "REVALIDATED" && !(mocked.res.statusCode === 404 && opts.unstable_onlyGenerated)) {
            throw new Error(`Invalid response ${mocked.res.statusCode}`);
        }
```

My error is coming from that `throw` at the end ... but that doesn't make any sense to me, because when I log `urlPath`, it's just the path I'm trying to refresh (eg. `/resource/5`).  When I try to hit that path with a GET request (either in my browser or through Postman) I *don't* get a redirect: I get a 200.

This led me to try adding a `/` to the end of my path:

```
response.revalidate(`/resource/${id}/`);
```

That got me a similar error, only this time it was for a 200 instead of a 308:

```
Error: Invalid response 200
```

So, it seems my status code doesn't actually matter: it's the `mocked.res.getHeader("x-nextjs-cache") !== "REVALIDATED"` part that's the problem.  However, digging through the code, I only found one place that sets that header.  It happens within a function within a function within a `renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl` function in `node_modules/next/dist/esm/server/base-server.js`:

```
if (isSSG && !this.minimalMode) {
        // set x-nextjs-cache header to match the header
        // we set for the image-optimizer
        res.setHeader("x-nextjs-cache", isOnDemandRevalidate ? "REVALIDATED" : cacheEntry.isMiss ? "MISS" : cacheEntry.isStale ? "STALE" : "HIT");
 }
```

... but when I add `console.log` statements it seems that code isn't being reached ... even though I see lots of other requests reaching it, and `isSSG && !this.minimalMode` is true for all of them.

So, in short, somehow the mock request `revalidate` makes isn't triggering the setting of that header, which then makes it fail ... but I have no clue why it's not getting to that header-setting code, because it's so deeply nested in the router code.

**END EDIT**

I also tried using `revalidatePath`, from `next/cache`:

```
revalidatePath(`/resource/[id]`);
```

but that also gives an error:

```
revalidatePath(`/resource/[id]`);

Error: Invariant: static generation store missing in revalidateTag /resource/[id]
    at revalidateTag (/home/me/project/next/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/revalidate-tag.js:15:15)
    at revalidatePath (/home/me/project/next/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/revalidate-path.js:13:45)
    at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/resource.js:88:67)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I think this is because `revalidatePath` is only intended to be used in the `/app` directory?

Finally, I found a reference to a `response.unstable_revalidate` method, which seemed to be designed for revalidating dynamic paths:

```
    response.unstable_revalidate(`/resource/${id}/`);
```

... but when I try to use it, it isn't there on the response:

```
TypeError: response.unstable_revalidate is not a function
    at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/resource.js:88:18)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Comment: What is your Next.js version? Also, can you double-check you are calling `revalidate` with the correct path? The error message suggests you are trying to revalidate `/resource/2153/edit` instead of `/resource/2153` - `Error: Failed to revalidate /resource/2153/edit`

Comment: 13.4.16.  And yeah, I was also trying to revalidate `/resource/5/edit` at the same time, but I was trying to keep the post simple by not mentioning the second route (and then I guess I accidentally copied the stack trace from the edit revalidate instead of the `/resource/5` one).  Thank you for catching that.  I've fixed the stack trace, and noticed that for the `/resource/5` one is failing because of a 200 (not a 308 like the `/edit`)... which makes even less sense to me :(

Comment: I just put together a quick test, and as I can see `revalidate` is working as expected. Do you think you can provide a minimal reproducible example? You can use the following working example as a template - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zen-wright-83kxjv?file=/pages/resource/[id].tsx

Comment: I tweaked your repro to create https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stupefied-flower-hj86y3?file=/pages/api/revalidate.ts:7,61.  It fails to update the timestamp, but it doesn't cause the error that I'm seeing, so I'll try to contrast my code with your simpler version and see if I can find the cause.

Comment: So are you using Pages Router (`/pages`) or App Router (`/app`)? Based on your original question I got the impression that you are using legacy pages router (`/pages`). But if your pages actually reside under the app router, you should use the the new `revalidatePath` / `revalidateTag` API and move your API route handler under the `/app` as well | https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath

Comment: I'm using both (which is supposed to be possible).  I transitioned the `/resource/5`  route to the `app` folder just fine, but when I tried to move `/route/5/edit` I ran into a bug (Next currently tries to pre-load all imports, which breaks the Knex library ... which that route uses ... because Knex conditionally imports a bunch of libraries which can't be pre-loaded).  But again, I don't want a `revalidate` route in my `app` folder, I want my `route/5/edit` route (trapped in `pages` until Next fixes their preloading) to revalidate the (`app`) `/route/5`.  Is that possible?

Comment: Not that it matters, but the reason I can't move the `/route/5/edit` route to the `app` folder is this bug: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/52091.  In that ticket they told me to use `serverComponentsExternalPackages`, but when I do that a million other things break :(

Comment: Have you tried revalidating `app` pages with `revalidatePath` / `revalidateTag`, and `pages` pages with `response.revalidate`? I highly suspect you can't mix and match these apis.

Comment: I have; see my original question (it gives a different error, "Error: Invariant: static generation store missing in revalidateTag /resource/[id]").  The Next docs say "The app directory works alongside the pages directory to allow for incremental adoption. This allows you to opt some routes of your application into the new behavior while keeping other routes in the pages directory for previous behavior." ... so the two definitely *can*  coexist ... but maybe they *can't* revalidate each others' routes?  That might just be the (sad) answer to this question.

Comment: Alright, scratch my last comment. `res.revalidate` can revalidate both `pages` and `app` pages. Is this what you are looking for? Please see working example here - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stackoverflow-76909444-1-jsg3nd

Comment: I don't know what to say, as I've simplified everything to be even simpler than your working example.  I've reduced my resource page to `return <div>hi</div>` with a `generateStaticParams` of `() => [5]`.  My revalidate route is just `await res.revalidate('/resource/5'); return res.status(404).json({ revalidated: true });`.  I even downgraded Next to your example's version, re-installed dependencies & wiped `.next` out ... STILL I get an error the moment I hit the revalidate route (now it's back to "Invalid response 308").  I have no clue what could be different from my code vs. your example.

Comment: Heck, I even made a brand new `/test` route (without even dynamic parameters), then changed my (two line) `/revalidate` route to revalidate it ... and I still get errors.  It's like there's something just broken in my Next installation (maybe the internal router that Next uses to perform revalidation?) that is simply stopping all revalidation across the board ... but I have no clue what it could be.

Comment: I'm not crazy!  I downloaded your sandbox, ran it, and clicked revalidation link.  At the command-line the server got: `Error: Invalid response 200
    at DevServer.revalidate (/home/me/project/test/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1300:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Server.<anonymous> (/home/me/project/test/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/server-ipc/index.js:55:30)`.  So either this is a Next-wide problem (not visible in sandbox) or my computer is flawed somehow.  What do you see, locally?

Comment: It's working as expected locally with Next.js 13.4.19. I didn't realize that sandbox was setup with outdated Next.js version, so I updated it to 13.4.19 as well - same result, no sign of error that you are seeing locally.

Comment: Well thank you, you've been a tremendous help.  I filed https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54420, and hopefully the developers will have some idea why this error only occurs on my machine.  In the meantime, if you want to summarize all of this in an answer that basically says "what you describe does work, here's a sandbox that proves it ... but you're having an environment-specific bug", I'll happily award the bounty to you.

Comment: Well, I was finally able to reproduce your error locally :) I can see your `Error: Invalid response 200` error in dev mode (`npm run dev`). There is no error in production build though (`npm run build && npm run start`). I'm not sure how much this helps you, but at least it solves one of the mysteries...

Comment: I didn't test revalidation in dev mode because there is no way to reliably test it as all pages are rendered on each page load. It sounds like you can work your error around with `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") { await res.revalidate(...) }` (I've updated my last sandbox accordingly)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to submit an answer? The bounty expires tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

1st option, on your `getStaticPaths` function, does it return

```
`return { paths, fallback: 'blocking' }`
```

> ```
> On Next JS documentation:
> { fallback: 'blocking' } will server-render pages on-demand if the path doesn't exist.
> ```

2nd option, on your `getStaticProps` function, try to omit `revalidate: true` or at least set it to `false`.

> Next js Documentation:
> If revalidate is omitted, Next.js will use the default value of false
> (no revalidation) and only revalidate the page on-demand when
> revalidate() is called.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Next.js docs here - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#on-demand-revalidation

You need to use `revalidatePath` or `revalidateTag` in Next.js 13 app router to revalidate based on path or tag respectively.

Comment: That is correct ... if the API route is in the `app` folder.  However, mine is in the `pages` folder, and those API routes are supposed to use `response.revalidate`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `res.revalidate`is the correct approach, and I'm just running into some sort of bug.  I've filed an issue with the Vercel team at https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54420, an am awaiting a response.

Answer (score -2):

There are a few issues here:

revalidate and revalidatePath are only meant to be used from GET handlers, not API routes. Since your editing handler is an API route, it won't work.

unstable_revalidate was removed in Next 11 in favor of the new invalidation API.

The recommended way to handle this now is:

In your API route, call the new invalidation API:

```
const { invalidatePages } = require('next/dist/server/ router')

// ...

await invalidatePages('/resource/[id]')
```

Add a revalidation hook in getStaticPaths:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // ...

  return {
    paths: paths,
    fallback: true
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // ...

  return {
    props: {},
    revalidate: 10 // revalidate every 10 seconds
  }
}
```

This will cause Next to re-render the dynamic page on invalidation.

The key points:

Use invalidatePages from API routes to trigger rebuilds
Add revalidation config to getStaticProps so Next knows when to re-render

Comment: There's literally no such method `invalidatePages` in Next.js (in `/next/didst/server/router` or anywhere else): https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Avercel%2Fnext.js%20invalidatePages&type=code